# Brute force MD5 hash in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, cryptography, md5

I have made a program that converts a string to a hash using MD5 algorithm.

```
   Public Shared Function getMD5Hash(ByVal strToHash As String) As String
    Dim md5Obj As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim bytesToHash() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strToHash)

    bytesToHash = md5Obj.ComputeHash(bytesToHash)

    Dim strResult As String = ""
    Dim b As Byte

    For Each b In bytesToHash
        strResult += b.ToString("x2")
    Next

    Return strResult
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox2.Text = getMD5Hash(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

But now I have added a button that will use brute force to find the original text when a MD5 hash is given.

What code can I write in the button to systematically try every word/number and check it against the original hash?

Answer (score 0):

> What code can I write in the button to systematically try every
>   word/number and check it against the original hash?

Looking at the current code and your enormous effort to create the Button, I would recommend, and it might sound a bit crazy, but what I really recommend for the code within  the button .... **VB.NET**

Comment: Sad attempt at being funny.

Comment: Then you learned driving a car before you learned how to drive a bike, too!?

Comment: Then you should be able to get this thing done easily, good luck ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can never find the guaranteed **original** text.  At best you can find a piece of text that has the same hash value, and so might, or might not, be the original code.

Your second problem is that MD5 is a cryptographic hash, and so has been explicitly designed to prevent someone doing what you are trying to do.  In effect you are attempting a [Preimage attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack) on MD5.

This is not impossible, but it is very difficult, and your final program could take decades to find a matching preimage.

Rather than spend that much time, I suggest you solve an easier version of the same problem.  Start with a short non-crypto hash, say 32 bit [FNV hash](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/).  Code that hash, and then try to find some text which produces the same hash as your original text.  FNV comes in different sizes, so you can try FNV-32, FNV-64, FNV-128 etc.  That will let you see the effect of increasing hash size on the difficulty of finding a Preimage.

Above all, make sure you have fun.

Comment: "At best you can find a piece of text that has the same hash value, and so might, or might not, be the original code." If by that you mean the algorithm has values that collide, wouldn't that act as a benefit to me? Isn't password authentication basically comparing the two hash values, and if they match, the user is authenticated? I am sorry but I am totally out of the loop here. 

About the time factor, yes I know it's practically useless, but if used as a dictionary attack it's not that bad. And my real purpose is not to break passwords but simply experiment with the code :)

Comment: You are right, there will be collisions, and yes that may reduce the time taken from centuries to decades.  If you are talking about password authentication, then you might want to read up about the use of [cryptographic salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) to defeat dictionary attacks.

Comment: Yes, I know about salted attacks, but my program only works for unsalted hashes. Doesn't really have any real use though, except maybe break an unsalted 4 letter password with symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I completed the program, and the code is very basic. It might have some errors.

```
    Dim done As Boolean

    Public Shared Function getMD5Hash(ByVal strToHash As String) As String
    Dim md5Obj As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim bytesToHash() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strToHash)

    bytesToHash = md5Obj.ComputeHash(bytesToHash)

    Dim strResult As String = ""
    Dim b As Byte

    For Each b In bytesToHash
        strResult += b.ToString("x2")
    Next

    Return strResult
    End Function 
'introduces MD5 Function


 Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As        System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

     'Added a background worker because I needed a stop button. 

    Dim password As String
    password = TextBox4.Text
    'the password is going to be in form of a hash, this is the hash the program will try to brute force  

    If TextBox4.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter a Password or Hash")

    Else

        Dim test() As String = {"", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v",
                                "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S",
                                "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "~", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^",
                                "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "-", "+", "="}
       'This array has all the characters the program will include in it's permutations and combinations



        For x As Integer = 0 To test.Length - 1
            Me.Button2.Enabled = True
            Console.WriteLine(test(x))
            For y As Integer = 0 To test.Length - 1
                Console.WriteLine(test(x) & test(y))
                For z As Integer = 0 To test.Length - 1
                    Console.WriteLine(test(x) & test(y) & test(z))
                    For q As Integer = 0 To test.Length - 1
                        Console.WriteLine(test(x) & test(y) & test(z) & test(q))
                        For j As Integer = 0 To test.Length - 1
                            Console.WriteLine(test(x) & test(y) & test(z) & test(q) & test(j))
  'this code runs the loop. It tries the characters in the "test" array. 
  'The maximum number of combination it can try is 5. (practically too slow to reach that number)

   TextBox3.Text = test(x) & test(y) & test(z) & test(q) & test(j)
                            TextBox3.Refresh()
                            Me.Refresh()
 'Textbox displays the combinations 


   If getMD5Hash(test(x) & test(y) & test(z) & test(q) & test(j)) = password Then
   'The word generated in the loop is converted in it's MD5 hash form. 

   MsgBox("Password is:" & test(x) & test(y) & test(z) & test(q) & test(j))
 If the hashed password matches the generated hash then a message is displayed:    Password is [the password in word form]

                              done = True
               'boolean done is set to true             
                     TextBox4.Text = ""
                     TextBox3.Text = ""
   End If



                        Next
                        If done = True Then Exit Sub
                    Next
                    If done = True Then Exit Sub
                Next
                If done = True Then Exit Sub
            Next
            If done = True Then Exit Sub
        Next
    End If
'This section stops the loop if the password is found OR if boolean done is true

    If done = True Then
        done = False
    End If
    TextBox3.Enabled = True
    TextBox4.Enabled = True 'after loop is completed the text boxes are enabled

End Sub


Private Sub Form7_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    done = True
    TextBox3.Enabled = True
    TextBox4.Enabled = True
'This button sets done to true and this stops the loop
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    done = False
    If done = False Then
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If
    TextBox3.Enabled = False
    TextBox4.Enabled = False
'This button starts the loop by running backgroundWorker and disables the textboxes
End Sub


End Class
```